# Using lotus.domino.Document as a parameter for a function, how do I recycle cleanly?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am programming a Server Task Add-In and am trying to make a clean, recyclable code. I am looping through a set of databases, then through some documents within the database.

```
    for (String serverAndFilename : listofServerFilenames) {
        String[] parts = serverAndFilename.split("!!");
        currentGECDB = session.getDatabase(parts[0], parts[1]);
        if (currentGECDB.isOpen()) {
        collSourceDocuments = currentGECDB.search(this
            .getSearchFormula(this
                .getvariablePartOfSearchFormula()));
        countOfSearchDocuments = collSourceDocuments.getCount();    
            docToChange = collSourceDocuments
                .getFirstDocument();
            while (docToChange != null) {
            if (changeNamesFieldsOnThisDocument(docToChange)) {
//                .... other code here
            } 
            tmpdoc = collSourceDocuments.getNextDocument();
            docToChange.recycle();
            docToChange = tmpdoc;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

I am concerned about the memory management issues with using a heavy Notes oject as a parameter to a Java function. Whilst checking the changes my function does, I am getting the 'old' values and need to make a recycle() on my document before re-retrieving the document.

It seems to me that I am forced to only pass primitives as arguments to an external function i.e.

```
public booleanfunction (String ServerName, String ReplicaIDOfDatabase, String UNIDofDocument)
```

but that would imply many subsequent OpenDatabase calls, which are expensive.

Is there a best way to do this?

As an example, this is part of a JUnit Test I am making on the result:

```
public void testNewArrivalTaskExample() {
try {
    testNewArrivalTask = GECTaskNewArrival.getTestTask(db, oli);
    testNewArrivalTask.save();

    Document testdocNewArrival_1 = getNewTestSourceCourrierDocument();
    for (NamesItemsInProcedure n : NamesItemsInProcedure.values()) {
    setNamesField(testdocNewArrival_1, n,
        GECTaskNewArrival.NEW_ARRIVAL_ROLE_MODEL,
        NamesItemsInProcedure.NOUVELLE_ARRIVEE);
    }

    testdocNewArrival_1.replaceItemValue("TestDocumentDescription",
        "NewArrival_AllFields");
    testdocNewArrival_1.save();

    GECTaskNewArrival gna = new GECTaskNewArrival(testNewArrivalTask,
        db, oli);

    gna.process();

    Item itemsuivi = testdocNewArrival_1
        .getFirstItem(NamesItemsInProcedure.SUIVI_COURRIER
            .getItemName());

    System.out.println("Content of document without recycle + rebirth:");
    printItemValuesToSysout(itemsuivi);

    System.out.println(NamesItemsInProcedure.SUIVI_COURRIER
        .getItemName()
        + " Should contain "
        + GECTaskNewArrival.NEW_ARRIVAL_NEWPERSON);

    String noteID = testdocNewArrival_1.getNoteID();
    testdocNewArrival_1.recycle();

    for (NamesItemsInProcedure n : NamesItemsInProcedure.values()) {
    boolean result = itemContainsThisForTestDoc(GECAlladin, noteID,
        n.getItemName(),
        GECTaskNewArrival.NEW_ARRIVAL_NEWPERSON);
    switch (n) {
    case ENCOURS_COURRIER:
        assertTrue(result);
        break;
    case AUTEURS_COURRIER:
        assertTrue(result);
        break;
    case SUIVI_COURRIER:
        assertTrue(result);
        break;
    case ECHEANCEMESSAGENOM_COURRIER:
        assertTrue(result);
        break;
    default:
        // assertFalse(result);
        break;

    }
    }

} catch (NotesException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and this is the console result:

```
Content of document without recycle + rebirth:

Suivi has these values:
Donald VieuxDeLaVieille/dsic/ville-ge`
the item belongs to this document 929E`
Suivi Should contain CN=Micky NouvelleArrivee/OU=salut/OU=Truc/O=Muche`

Suivi has these values:`
Donald VieuxDeLaVieille/dsic/ville-ge`
CN=Micky NouvelleArrivee/OU=salut/OU=Truc/O=Muche`
the item belongs to this document 929E`
Suivi contains CN=Micky NouvelleArrivee/OU=salut/OU=Truc/O=Muche`
```

I am still stumped.

Comment: I've seen no evidence of any problems passing NotesDocument objects to functions. I do it routinely.  What do you mean by 'old' values?

Comment: I start with a Document. Item 'Status' has the value 'Start'. I then do some processing on the Document (changing the item to 'End'), make a save(). When I look into the document in the database using ScanEZ, the Status item has the value 'Start', as I am expecting, but in my code, when I do `item = doc.getfirstitem("Status"); String status = item.getItemValueString(), the answer is 'Start' and not 'End'. If I take the NoteID of the document, recycle it, the reload it with the noteID, then I get 'End'

Comment: Perhaps there's a typo above?  If ScanEZ is saying the value is "Start", and getItemValueString() is giving you "Start", that seems like it's correct behavior.  Or at least consistent behavior.  Did you really mean to say that ScanEZ is saying the value is "End"?  Can you replicate this in a small piece of agent code that you can post in its entirety?

Comment: Richard, I have included an example of the JUnit Test I am using.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand...  You are saying that Item 'suivi' in Document testdocNewArrival_1 is updated and the document is saved inside the function setNamesField(), but after the function returns and you do a new itemsuivi = GetFirstItem("suivi") and then you call printItemValuesToSysout(), and the updated value is not shown.  So the in-memory Document object does not have the new value.  But after you recycle testdocNewArrival_1 and call itemContainsForThisTestDoc and reload the document by NoteID, the new in-memory Document object does have the new value.  That is very strange.

Comment: Is there any change if you get rid of this code?       testdocNewArrival_1.replaceItemValue("TestDocumentDescription",
        "NewArrival_AllFields");
    testdocNewArrival_1.save();

Comment: Yes, strange, isn't it? One possible hypothesis is that I am running the code directly in a standalone myEclipse, using Notes.jar. That might be the cause. I will test your suggestion, but since it's midnight here, will report the result next week. Your help is invaluable, if only just to confirm that I am slowly turning mad! As you say, I would be expecting that the in-memory Document object gets updated when I do the saves, in fact it should be getting updated without the saves, and I don't get where the disconnect is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing your code from this:

```
tmpdoc = collSourceDocuments.getNextDocument();
```

to this:

```
tmpdoc = collSourceDocuments.getNextDocument(docToChange);
```

According to the doc, omitting the Document argument from the getNextDocument call should work, but my understanding is that there are different implementations internally for the DocumentCollection depending on how the collection was built, and I'm thinking that omitting the Document argument might be giving you some strange results (i.e., explaining the 'old' values you are seeing) in the case of a DocumentCollection created by Database.search().

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Richard. I'm more concerned with the `if (changeNamesFieldsOnThisDocument(docToChange))` line. I am sending a Document as a parameter, which makes a copy of the reference, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it's a copy of the object reference, but the reference is to the same Document object.  The back-end classes make sure that there is only one memory allocation to worry about per Document object, no matter how many references to the same Document you have.  The same is true for other Notes object types as well, and that's why it's possible, if you're not careful, for code in one function to recycle a Document or View out from under code in another Document that still needs it -- which is a particular danger in multi-threaded code.

Comment: I have changed the code as you described, but alas! to no avail.